# DOS Character for Smiley Face?

Tags: c, character, dos

Does anyone know the bits involved in printing a smiley face in DOS?

Talking about this character: ☺

By bits I mean the bits in the character (or int) such that I could specify those bits in C and have it print a smiley face.

Comment: [recommended read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455047/why-does-printf-c-1-return-smiley-face-instead-of-coded-char-for-1) (all of it - including the comments)

Answer (score 4):

Try running this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
     cout<<i<<"\t"<<char(i)<<endl;
}
```

Edit: It appears to be char(1)

Comment: Note that the answer may depend on which DOS code page you have selected (although the first 31 'control' characters are usually fairly constant between code pages).

Answer (score 0):

It's the integer 1

Here's the examples for code page 437:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Answer (score -3):

Do this keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Comment: The question is not about how to print the character but abouts its bit code in DOS.