# Why does printf( "%c", 1) return smiley face instead of coded char for 1

Tags: c, terminal, character-encoding, printf, character

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x,y;

int main( void )
{
    for ( x = 0; x < 10; x++, printf( "\n" ) )
        for ( y = 0; y < 10; y++ )
            printf( "%c", 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

It returns smiley faces. I searched everywhere for a code for smiley face or a code for 1 but I didn't manage to find any links whatsoever or any explanation why char value for 1 returns smiley face, when the ascii code for 1 is SOH. I researched answers for this question but I didn't find any answers that explain why this happens.

Comment: You're going to want to note the terminal info you're running this one. If you don't think it's important, think again.

Comment: I do not get a smiley with this code...

Comment: @malkat google "terminal code page"

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks! I was struggling to find a connection but was able to find out mine was using page 437 by typing chcp in the cmd. Now I see why I got the characters I was getting by typing different numbers.

Comment: the '%c' is expecting a single char, however, `1` is a multichar integer.  Suggest using: `printf( "%d", 1 );`

Answer (score 6):

The output varies among different terminals. For example, on my OS X default terminal, no characters are output.

In your case, `☺` is output presumably due to [some historical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). In short, this is because code page 437, which maps byte `0x01` to `U+263A`, is the character set of MS-DOS.

Comment: Thank you! I had to search for the active code page in cmd to get to the map of characters that my windows console uses (page 437)

Answer (score 2):

Because `1` isn't a printable character code. If you want `'1'` you need to write it with the character literal:

```
 printf( "%c", '1' );
            // ^^^
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to print 1, he wants to print the char whose ascii is 1

Comment: @GauravSehgal Well as I mentioned it's not a printable character.

Comment: Yes that's true, but why is he getting a smiley?

Comment: @GauravSehgal That depends on the terminal and how nonprintable characters are represented.

Comment: @GauravSehgal: Because if you're not printing certain control characters, on a Windows console you might get an OEM character. Which happens to be a smiley.

Comment: Not to mention that smiley is a much nicer thing to get than, say, a segfault :)

Comment: @HighPredator Why should that give a segfault ever?

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it should not. Was trying to making a joke.

Comment: @ cHao Thanks a lot for the answer! Where can I get the OEM listing for Windows? It shows the smiley face even if I type 2 for example but if I enter 65 it prints A (like it should I suppose).

Comment: @malkat it depends on what [terminal code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) is configured as to what character values `< 32` and `> 127` produce, that is, outside the range of ASCII printable characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a number, you'll select a character number from ASCII table, if you use a `char` you'll find the char.

Example: this code prints the ASCII character number 65:

```
printf( "%c", 65 ); // Outputs: A
```

This code prints the letter A:

```
printf( "%c", 'A' ); // Outputs: A
```

Comment: It does not output `A`, it was a mistake.

Comment: `printf( "%c", 65 ); // Outputs: A` - [not on my mainframe terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout). And that, kids, is one of the many reasons magic number programming is a bad idea.

Comment: this is an example

Comment: @maltkat: `65` is a magic number here. If you find such code without any comment it's not clear what the `65` is for, as it would give different result on different platforms. As *WhozCraig* mentioned, there are other character-sets then ASCII around and in use.

Comment: not necessarily true,  For instance if if the underlying char set is EBCDIC then what is output will be quite different than what is output with a ASCII char set.  and which `code page` is currently selected will also result in different output