# How to Display a Smiley Face in C++ Console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, windows-7, windows-10

When I use to have Windows 7, I use to be able to use certain codes for my C++ programs to create acsii symbols. For example, if I did "cout << (char)1;" my program would display a white smiley face in the console box. Now since I updated to Windows 10, those codes do not work anymore.

I've done research and figured out the unicode from Windows 10 has changed. In the link below, I use to be able to use symbol/code 1 through 31 but now they appear not to work on Windows 10.

Link: https://www.alt-codes.net/

My question is, is there anyway to be able to get codes 1-31 back, possibly by downloading the Windows 7 unicode or is there a new symbol to paste the smiley face from the link? And if that's the case, how would I show it from doing this: "cout << (char) ??? ";

When I use cout < (char)1, it displays displays a box with a question mark inside of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf( "%c", 1) return smiley face instead of coded char for 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455047/why-does-printf-c-1-return-smiley-face-instead-of-coded-char-for-1)

Comment: No. I still run into the same problem. The code displays a box with a question mark inside of it.

Comment: May I suggest that if the content you want to display to your user cannot be expressed in a standard written language, then a console application is not the appropriate format for your program.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley What I'm creating is a console game and for it's purpose, it is appropriate for what I need it for.

Comment: Can't you use the Unicode symbol for the characters in the proper encoding for `std::cout`? Well, on Windows, using` wchar_t` and UTF-16 would likely be easier.

Comment: That behavior was inconsistent in the legacy console. If you typed Ctrl+A, it would be echoed as "^A" and read as "\x01". However, if "\x01" was printed, internally the console would call `MultiByteToWideChar` with the flag `MB_USEGLYPHCHARS` (if already a `WCHAR` it was first cast to `char`), which for an OEM codepage such as 437 or 850 would return U+263A (white smiling face). Then of course when you copied it from the console it would be the smiling face instead of the "\x01" control character that was actually written.

Comment: It is not that codepage 437 maps 0x01 to 0x263A. Windows codepages are supersets of ASCII. You only get these glyphs with the  `MB_USEGLYPHCHARS` compatibility flag. I urge you to use the actual Unicode characters with the console's wide-character API instead of relying on this legacy flag to map ASCII control characters to the glyphs that were displayed for control characters on old IBM PCs.

Comment: @eryksun  I understand that you don't recommend it, but I need it for my computer. How would I be able to get the MB_USEGLYPHCHARS compatibility flag? All I want is those symbols to appear on my C++ programs so when I use "cout << (char)1" a smiley face will appear.

Comment: If you think you can make `cout << (char)1` work without using the legacy console (an option in the console properties), then you misunderstood me. Formerly the legacy console was doing this conversion for you, and it was an inconsistent hack. The new console doesn't do it. If you want to continue abusing ASCII control character 0x01 (i.e. Ctrl+A, i.e. SOH) as if it's U+263A, then you'll need a function that maps it via `MultiByteToWideChar`; then write it to the console via the wide-character function `WriteConsoleW`. Or you could just stop using legacy assumptions from the 1980s...

Comment: @eryksun I simply cannot express the amount of thank yous I want to give you. I checked the legacy console in the console properties. You have fixed my problem and answered my question. How can I up vote your comment for answering a question? Again, thank you so much.