# ANDing two characters and assigning the result to the first one

Tags: c#

I am ANDing two characters and assigning the result to the first character.
'a'
'\u0889'

```
'a'      in binary 00000000 01100001
'\u0889' in binary 00001000 10001001
So the & will be   00000000 00000001
```

Why does it output the ☺ emoji

```
    char comp58 = 'a';
    char comp96 ='\u0889';
    Console.WriteLine(comp96&=comp58);
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455047/why-does-printf-c-1-return-smiley-face-instead-of-coded-char-for-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you are ANDing the two characters, the result is explicitly casted as a character. And it turns out that ASCII character 1 (start of heading), when rendered, is a smiley face ☺.

So what you are doing is:

```
char comp58 = 'a';
char comp96 ='\u0889';
comp96 &= comp58; 
Console.WriteLine(comp96); // comp96 is a character and is treated as one. ASCII 1 is smiley face.
```

If you want to output as an integer you need to convert it to an integer.

```
Console.WriteLine((int)(comp96&=comp58));
```

or

```
char comp58 = 'a';
char comp96 ='\u0889';
int andResult = com96 & comp58;
Console.WriteLine(andResult);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is ASCII 1 an emojii? Am I getting something wrong? Why does the result of AND ing two chars return an int?

Comment: Hmm, pretty sure that *that* smiley is not ASCII 1

Comment: @EricMovsessian It is set out to be that way. Normally ASCII 1 is something called SOH start of the heading (https://www.asciitable.com/) but most systems render ASCII 1 as a smiley face for convention purposes. You can type ASCII characters on your keyboard if you have a Numpad. ASCII 1 is ☺, 2 is ☻, 3 is ♥, and so on and so forth. Also characters are represented as numbers (hence the ASCII) and anding two numbers will result in a number.

Comment: @CaiusJard of course ASCII 1 is not smiley face (may have misphrased it on the answer) but when it is cast to a character it is rendered that way.

Comment: Thank you very much @ÖzgürGüzeldereli, It is absolutely clear now.

Comment: I am sorry but I forgot to ask this:
if the char type has range of up to 65535 than whenever we convert the result to a char why doesn't it understand anything higher than 127(ASCII)?

Comment: @EricMovsessian It does, there can be many reasons why it seems like it can't. One could be that your computer cannot render the character, not all characters are renderable. But all in all saying ```char a = (char)384;``` or ```char something = (char)65500;``` is totally ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces the exact result you can expect.

internaly the characters are utf-16 so

'a' (or as unicode written '\u0061') is in binary representation 00000000 01100001 (97 in decimal)
'\u0889' is in binary representation 00001000 10001001 (2185 in decimal)

a bitwise and will result in 00000000 00000001 or in decimal 1

Then you write this unicode character to a non unicode console. On my system for example the console uses CP850. And when you look that up here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850. This Codepage shares the first half wit CP437 that you can lookup here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters an the character with code 1 is the smiley face

You could use `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` to change your console encoding to utf-8 or switch to any encoding you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, so How do I know which codepage my Console uses?

Comment: @EricMovsessian I edited my answer to show you how to switch your console encoding. To check what your default encoding is you could open cmd.exe -> click on the top left on the cmd icon -> click "Properties" -> in the lower region of the window you should see "Current code Page"

Comment: Okay, I checked and It is 437. I feel bad for asking this, but I have too. Howe do codepages relate to Encodings? As far as I got It is like this. Encoding is how the chars are presented in bytes and codepages show what chars can be displayed but I mean, shouldn't these two be the same?

Comment: It's the same thing. In the old days we startet with ASCII, which is an 7-bit encoding = 128 different characters. But over time and usage of computers in different countries with different langages it was necessary to add language specific characters, so Codpages were added (8th bit) so after the first 128 characters from ASCII there are now 128 region specific characters added, CP437 for US, CP850 for german speaking countries, ... But 256 characters is still very little so things like UCS-2/UTF-16 or later UTF-8 were developt to have codes for millions and millions of characters.

Comment: For a very entertaining way to learn more about encodings you could watch https://youtu.be/_mZBa3sqTrI

Comment: Thank you, It definitely was entertaining.